# ¿Cómo podría quedarme con aquellas filas en que la diferencia de horas, con la anterior, sea inferior a 3 horas en R?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo una cuestión que espero que me puedan resolver. Dispongo de 2000 obs con 3 variables. En este caso tengo las variables de doctor, usuario y fecha_hora_visita, que se verían así:

```
doctor    usuario    fecha_hora_visita
10        1          15/02/2015 10:09
10        1          15/02/2015 11:16
10        7          16/02/2015 08:05
10        7          16/02/2015 08:35 
10        7          16/02/2015 11:46
10        7          16/02/2015 11:55
10        7          16/02/2015 12:00
```

Lo que me gustaría es, de un mismo usuario, manteniendo la fecha, poder eliminar aquellas horas de visita superiores a 3 horas. Es decir, del usuario 1 se mantendrían las dos filas, ya que entre las 10:09 y las 11:16 no hay una diferencia de 3 horas.

En cambio, del usuario 7 sería eliminar la fecha y hora (16/02/2015 11:46), ya que de 08:35 a 11:46 hay una diferencia superior a 3 horas. Pero manteniendo la hora siguiente, ya que de 11:55 a 12:00 no hay 3 horas de diferencia, quedando por tanto así:

```
doctor    usuario    fecha_hora_visita
10        1          15/02/2015 10:09
10        1          15/02/2015 11:16
10        7          16/02/2015 08:05
10        7          16/02/2015 08:35 
10        7          16/02/2015 11:55
10        7          16/02/2015 12:00
```

He separado la fecha y hora en dos columnas, para ver si de este modo, podía conseguirlo más fácilmente, pero no me ha sido posible.

Espero puedan ayudarme. Se lo agradezco de antemano.

Comment: si adjuntas el archivo o una parte te podremos ayudar mejor.

Comment: ¿La diferencia de las tres horas es desde la mínima hora del día?. Por ejemplo, si el usuario 3 tiene el mismo día las horas 9:00, 10:00, 11:00 y 13:00, si tomamos como referencia las 9:00 descartamos las 13:00 pero si tomamos como referencia las 11:00 no podemos descartar ninguna porque no hay diferencia de 3 horas.

Comment: No, la diferencia de horas, sería del mismo día, la anterior, es decir, si el día 16, tiene horas a las 9:00, 10:00, 13:15 y 14:00. Sólo se eliminaría la de las 13:15, porque es 3 horas superior a la anterior, no sé si me explico. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando R base:

```
lapply(split(df, list(df$doctor, df$usuario, format(df$fecha_hora_visita, "%d/%m/%Y")), drop=TRUE), 
       FUN=function(x) x[c(TRUE,diff(x[,'fecha_hora_visita']) < as.difftime(3, units = "hours")), ]
       ) -> lista
do.call(rbind, lista)
    
       doctor usuario   fecha_hora_visita
10.1.1     10       1 2015-02-15 10:09:00
10.1.2     10       1 2015-02-15 11:16:00
10.7.3     10       7 2015-02-16 08:05:00
10.7.4     10       7 2015-02-16 08:35:00
10.7.6     10       7 2015-02-16 11:55:00
10.7.7     10       7 2015-02-16 12:00:00
```

La idea sería:

1. Si ya tienes ordenados los datos, podemos usar `split` para armar una lista separando cada grupo de `doctor` y  `ususario`
2. Luego con `lapply()` aplicamos una función para quedarnos con los casos dónde `fecha_hora_visita` sea menor a 180 minutos.
3. Volvemos a reconstruir el `data.frame` desde la lista mediante `do.call(rbind, lista)`

Comment: Hola Patricio, le agradezco su respuesta. Probando lo que comenta, me pasa que se me eliminan horas, que no entiendo por qué lo hacen:

Original:
doctor usuario fecha_hora_visita 
1 2 26/02/2015 18:46 
1 2 26/02/2015 19:21 
1 2 26/02/2015 22:24 
1 2 27/02/2015 10:08 
1 2 27/02/2015 15:25 
1 2 04/03/2015 19:12 
1 2 07/03/2015 19:54 
1 2 07/03/2015 20:19 
1 2 07/03/2015 20:33 
1 2 16/03/2015 9:42 
1 2 23/03/2015 20:37 
1 2 23/03/2015 21:18

Comment: Después de hacerlo como me comenta, me queda:

doctor usuario fecha_hora_visita 
1 2 26/02/2015 18:46 
1 2 26/02/2015 19:21 
1 2 04/03/2015 19:12 
1 2 07/03/2015 19:54 
1 2 07/03/2015 20:19 
1 2 07/03/2015 20:33 
1 2 16/03/2015 9:42 
1 2 23/03/2015 21:18

Entiendo que elimine la fecha del 1 2 26/02/2015 22:24, porque es superior en 3 horas a la anterior, igual que 1 2 27/02/2015 15:25.

Pero no entiendo porque se eliminan:  1 2 27/02/2015 10:08, ni esta fecha 1 2 23/03/2015 20:37 

Ya me dice. Gracias

Comment: Se elimina por que la diferencia con la observación anterior es de más de 3 horas, entiendo ahora por tu comentario que el agrupamiento debiera además ser por día. Revisa mi edición

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio, me funcionó esto que me dijo :). Aprovecho para hacerle una pregunta más. Ahora que ya dispongo de aquellas horas que me interesan en base a los días. ¿cómo podría hacer para quedarme tan sólo con los días repetidos? 

Es decir, de este conjunto de datos, eliminar aquellas fechas que no se repitan o sólamente seleccionar aquellas que sean iguales, no sé si me explico. Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Y como se sabría cuales son esos días "repetidos"? podría ser una pregunta interesante te sugiero que armes otra. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio, lo hago ahora :)

Answer (score 1):

El siguiente código te puede ayudar, (Agregue una explicación en los comentarios)

```
#Cargamos las librerias necesarias
library(tibble) #Para generar la tabla de datos
library(lubridate) #Para operar con fechas y horas
library(dplyr) #Para manipular la tabla de datos
library(tidyr) #Para manipular la tabla de datos

#Generamos un data.frame como en tu ejemplo
df<-tribble(
~doctor,    ~usuario,    ~fecha_hora_visita,
10,        1,          "15/02/2015 10:09",
10,        1,          "15/02/2015 11:16",
10,        7,          "16/02/2015 08:05",
10,        7,          "16/02/2015 08:35", 
10,        7,          "16/02/2015 11:46",
10,        7,          "16/02/2015 11:55",
10,        7,          "16/02/2015 12:00"
)


df%>%
    #Separamos fecha_hora_visita en fecha y hora para poder agrupar por fecha
    separate(fecha_hora_visita,c("Fecha","Hora"), " ",remove = F)%>%
    #Combertimos fecha_hora_visita de caracter a formato de fecha (POSIXct) con lubridate
    mutate(Hora=dmy_hm(fecha_hora_visita))%>%
    #Agrupamos por usuario y fecha
    group_by(usuario,Fecha)%>%
    #Calculamos la diferencia en horas del un registro con el anterior por usuario y fecha
    mutate(dif_horas=difftime(Hora,lag(Hora,default=Hora[1]),units = "hours"))%>%
    #Desagrupamos
    ungroup()%>%
    #Filtramos los registros donde la diferencia en horas es menor a 3
    filter(dif_horas<3)#%>%
    #Eliminamos las v.a. auxiliares que creamos en el proceso
    #select(-Fecha,-Hora,-dif_horas)
```

La salida es la siguiente que es muy similar a la salida esperada, pero contiene algunas variables extra que nos auxiliaron en el proceso (`Fecha`, `Hora`, `dif_hors`), si des-comentas el ultimo reglón del código y el pipe (`%>%`) del penúltimo reglón puedes eliminarlas.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  doctor usuario fecha_hora_visita Fecha      Hora                dif_horas     
   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>             <chr>      <dttm>              <drtn>        
1     10       1 15/02/2015 10:09  15/02/2015 2015-02-15 10:09:00 0.00000000 ho~
2     10       1 15/02/2015 11:16  15/02/2015 2015-02-15 11:16:00 1.11666667 ho~
3     10       7 16/02/2015 08:05  16/02/2015 2015-02-16 08:05:00 0.00000000 ho~
4     10       7 16/02/2015 08:35  16/02/2015 2015-02-16 08:35:00 0.50000000 ho~
5     10       7 16/02/2015 11:55  16/02/2015 2015-02-16 11:55:00 0.15000000 ho~
6     10       7 16/02/2015 12:00  16/02/2015 2015-02-16 12:00:00 0.08333333 ho~
```

La clave de todo fue la función `difftime` que es la función de R base usada para calcular la diferencia entre fechas y/o horas.

Comment: Hola Rolando, le agradezco su respuesta. Prové lo que comentó, pero me quita columnas que no entiendo el porque me las quita. Por ejemplo:

Original:
doctor    usuario    fecha_hora_visita
1           2            26/02/2015 18:46
1 2 26/02/2015 19:21
1 2 26/02/2015 22:24
1 2 27/02/2015  10:08
1 2 27/02/2015  15:25
1 2 04/03/2015 19:12
1 2 07/03/2015 19:54
1 2 07/03/2015 20:19
1 2 07/03/2015 20:33
1 2 16/03/2015 9:42
1 2 23/03/2015 20:37
1 2 23/03/2015 21:18

Comment: Me queda de la siguiente manera:

doctor usuario fecha_hora_visita
1 2 26/02/2015 18:46
1 2 26/02/2015 19:21
1 2 29/02/2015  10:08
1 2 04/03/2015 19:12
1 2 07/03/2015 20:19
1 2 07/03/2015 20:33
1 2 16/03/2015 9:42
1 2 23/03/2025 21:18

Me ha eliminado la fecha: 26/02/2015 22:24 (lo entiendo, porque esta tiene una diferencia superior a 3 horas con la anterior). Igual que 29/02/2015 15:25.

En cambio, me elimina: 07/03/2015 19:54 cuando la anterior pertenece a otro día. Igual sucede con: 23/03/2015 20:37.

Quedo atento a su respuesta. Gracias